# background refresh information from database AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have created a website which retrieves text which has been uploaded to my database. the problem with this is i want a refresh of the content from that database ever second. but i can't find how to do this anywhere. i want this done in the background. and if possible a way to make the textbook that i will put in later to input the data into the server, also not do a full refresh but send the content in the background. thank you every answer will count.

```html
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "myDB";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<div id='message'> <br> ". $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"] . "<br> </div>";
     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a file, simply echo out the results. Then in another file, load the echoed results in a div like this:

`db_results.php` file which will echo out results:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $dbname = "myDB";


    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             echo "<p>". $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"] . "</p>";
         }
    } else {
         echo "0 results";
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

`display.php` file which will refresh the results in a div:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setInterval(function() {
                $("#load_results").load("db_results.php");
            }, 1000);
        });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "load_results"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`db_results.php` file will query database, will fetch the results and will echo them out. The second file (`display.php`) loads the first file in a div and refreshes the div every second, so updated results are loaded in the concerned div.

P.S.: Keep both files in same directory or adjust the path accordingly.

Comment: Thanks ill check this code and see if it works for me later.

Comment: Nice and easy - works for me. 
BTW. In real situations, how often we can try to refresh value from database to make sure this will not kill the system?